# Returning Empty list while getting text from span tag (Web scraping)

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the product price and name from [this](https://www.daraz.com.np/televisions/?spm=a2a0e.11779170.cate_3.1.287d2d2bmERvcc) URL.

When I inspect the HTML element, the price of the product is under a `span` tag with the class name `c13VH6`.

However, I am getting an empty string.

Below is my code.

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) 
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3'}


html_text=requests.get('https://www.daraz.com.np/televisions/? 
spm=a2a0e.11779170.cate_3.1.287d2d2bmERvcc',headers=headers).text

soup=BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'lxml')
#soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html5lib')

string1=soup.find('span',class_='c13VH6')
print(soup.find('span', class_='c13VH6'))
print(string1)
```

Comment: There's no `class="c13VH6"` in the HTML.

Comment: The elements you're looking for are added dynamically by JavaScript. You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is loaded dynamically, therefore the `requests` module won't support it. However, the data is embedded on the website in JSON format, you can find the data using the built-in [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) (regex) module, and convert it to a Python dictionary (`dict)` and access the `key`/`value`'s using the built-in [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) module.

For example, to print all the products names and prices:

```
import json
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
url = "https://www.daraz.com.np/televisions/?spm=a2a0e.11779170.cate_3.1.287d2d2bmERvcc"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "lxml")

json_data = json.loads(re.search("window\.pageData=({.*})", str(soup)).group(1))

# To view all the JSON data:
# print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=3))

for data in json_data["mods"]["listItems"]:
    print(data["name"])
    print(data["priceShow"].split()[1])
    print("-" * 80)
```

Output:

```
SONY  Klv-32W602D 32 Class Hdr Led Smart Tv - (Black)"
59,500
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SONY  Bravia Klv32R302E 32" Hd Led Tv
48,000
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung  Ua49N5300Arshe 49 Inch Full Hd Smart Led Tv - Black
87,290
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
X96 Mini, Android Box, Make Your Any TV Smart & 4K
4,200
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sansui 43S803A 43 Inch Screen 1080P Led Tv
50,369
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Samsung  Ua49Nu7100Rshe 49 Inch 4K Ultra Hd Smart Led Tv - Black
128,690
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...
```