# html scraping returns empty text and value fileds

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the available rooms from [this](https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id=92) booking website. My Attempt:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#FORMAT: TT_tt_MMM_jjjj
#At max 2 weeks in advance
date = "Sa 23 Sep 2023"
min_space = 3
only_big_rooms = False
hut_id = 92


URL = "https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id=" + str(hut_id)


response = requests.get(URL)
#print(response.text)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

for i in range(0,13):
    bookingID = "bookingDate" + str(i)
    block = soup.find('div', {'id':bookingID})
    if (block.text == date):
        print("found it once!")
    print(block.text)
    print(block)

#also failed: 
for i in range(0,13):
    bookingID = "bookingDateHidden" + str(i)
    block = soup.find('input', {'id':bookingID})
    if (block.text == date):
        print("found it once!")
    print(block.value)
    print(block)
```

When running the code, all the labels and texts the code gets from the site are empty. So my console output looks like this:

```
moritz@cupid:~$ python3 Alpines_scraper.py 
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate0"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate1"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate2"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate3"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate4"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate5"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate6"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate7"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate8"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate9"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate10"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate11"></div>
<div class="main-label" id="bookingDate12"></div>
None
<input id="bookingDateHidden0" type="hidden"/>
None
<input id="bookingDateHidden1" type="hidden"/>
None
<input id="bookingDateHidden2" type="hidden"/>
...
```

After a bit of research, I found out, that my site probably didn't load the content at the stage of the request. Then I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67310293/returning-empty-list-while-getting-text-from-span-tag-web-scraping) SO post, but couldn't really wrap my head around it. Since this is my first try at web scraping.

If someone is willing to help me, or knows of a tutorial, that deals with this kind of problem, I'd be happy to hear from you.

Comment: Use Selenium, view-source:https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id=92 data is loaded via javascript

Comment: Or perhaps it's already in the HTML but in a different place, I haven't checked. Main thing is, the html elements you're grabbing `bookingDate0`, `bookingDate1`, etc... it's empty if you check the source with `view-source` or `Ctrl+U`

Comment: ok, thanks. when I viewed the SC (with CTRL + shift + C in Firefox) all the texts were populated, so thought, i could grab it simpler. 
when unsing CTRL + U im seeing some JS. so i am looking into selenium now.

Comment: That opens developer tools, that will show you the current DOM not the HTML the server sends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when a page is loaded dynamically you should use Selenium, but sometimes you can work out where the data is coming from by looking at the Network tab in developer tools. Once you've found it you can just make a request which is faster than using Selenium.

For the website you're trying to scrape, it calls `$.getJSON('/reservation/selectDate?date=' + dateText, ...` to load the data. In the Network tab, you can see a request for `/reservation/selectDate?date=12.09.2023`.

If you visit that URL without first visiting `/reservation/calendar` you get an error. If you try to scrape that URL, it will return a page about cookies not being enabled. If you look at the cookies the page has set in Application > Cookies in developer tools, you can see there are `JSESSIONID` and `SRVGROUP` cookies. The first of these seems to affect the result. To get a `JSESSIONID` you can make a HEAD request to `/reservation/calendar?hut_id=92` and then request `/reservation/selectDate` with that session id. A HEAD request is used because it will get the cookie without having to load the whole page. This will then return JSON which you can then parse.

This can be done as follows:

```
import requests
from datetime import datetime

ROOM_MAP = {4: "large rooms", 5: "shared bedrooms"}

today = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")

r = requests.head("https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id=92")
session_id = r.cookies.get("JSESSIONID")

if not session_id:
    print("Couldn't get JSESSIONID")
    exit(1)

cookies = {
    "JSESSIONID": session_id
}

r = requests.get("https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/selectDate",
                 params = {"date": today}, cookies = cookies)

# Check we have recieved JSON
if r.headers["Content-Type"].startswith("application/json"):
    for date in r.json().values():
        print(date[0]["reservationDate"])
        for room_type in date:
            print(room_type["freeRoom"], ROOM_MAP[room_type["bedCategoryId"]])
else:
    print("Scrape failed")
```

**Edit - Dynamically generating `ROOM_MAP`**

You can generate `ROOM_MAP` for each page by using beautiful soup to parse it. You can install it with `pip install bs4`.

Looking at the page source, the room type names are already there. For `hut_id=297` for example, `#bedCategoryLabel0-7` is `Large rooms`. The first number is the key from the JSON (which we can ignore) and the second is the `bedCategoryId`. The CSS selector `[id^=bedCategoryLabel0-]` will get all elements whose id begins with `bedCategoryLabel0-`, which will be the name of each room type. The mapping can then be generated from the number at the end of the id and the text in the element. To add this to the original code, first add `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`, then removed the hardcoded `ROOM_MAP` and then change the first request to

```
today = datetime.now().strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
# BEGIN CHANGES
r = requests.get("https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar",
                 params={"hut_id": hut_id})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
ROOM_MAP = {int(e["id"].split("-")[1]): e.get_text(strip=True) for e in soup.select("[id^=bedCategoryLabel0-]")}
# END CHANGES
session_id = r.cookies.get("JSESSIONID")
```

Notice that the HEAD has been replaced with GET because we need the content. The content is parsed with beautiful soup which then finds the relevant elements using `.select`. The id is split to get the number at the end (the `bedCategoryId`) which is mapped to the text of the element with whitespace removed. `ROOM_MAP` can then be used as before.

Comment: Thanks, of all the given answers, yours was working best in my use case. (and maybe gave me a good hint at processing the data)
So It was working like I expected, up to the point where I was using another hut to make the script more general, (e.g. 297) where the "bedCategoryId"=4 doesn't match with the "large rooms" anymore. Did you find the assignments by checking values to the site, or is there a assignment sheet, that I am missing?

Comment: @Moritz Have a look at my edited answer

Answer (score 2):

As hinted at in the comments, the data is loaded dynamically, so it is not in the html code. Upon inspecting the developer tools the API endpoint can be found, which can then be queried directly to collect the data:

```
import requests

hut_id = 92

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'referer': f'https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id={hut_id}'
}

params = {
    'date': '12.09.2023',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    # First visit the referer page to potentially receive initial cookies
    session.get(f'https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id={hut_id}', headers=headers)

    # Now make the actual request with the session, which now contains the cookies
    response = session.get('https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/selectDate', params=params, headers=headers)

data = response.json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way of getting the booking for a particular day/hut, by observing the network calls made by page (see Dev tools -- Network tab -- XHR calls in browser):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd



headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'
}

s = requests.Session()
s.headers.update(headers)
s.get('https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/calendar?hut_id=92')
r = s.get('https://www.alpsonline.org/reservation/selectDate?date=15.09.2023')
json_list = []
for i, value in r.json().items():
    json_list.append(value[0])
df = pd.DataFrame(json_list)
print(df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
    hutBedCategoryId    bedCategoryId   bedCategoryType bookingEnabled  closed  events  freeRoom    futureHutOccupancyShown reservationDate totalRoom   contingentId    contingentText  contingentTitle unserviced  unservicedWaitingList   hutDefaultLanguage  reservedRoomsRatio  eventsAsString
0   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  3   False   15.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.903226    
1   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  0   False   16.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   1.000000    
2   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  29  False   17.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.064516    
3   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  23  False   18.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.258065    
4   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  17  False   19.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.451613    
5   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  0   False   20.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   1.000000    
6   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  22  False   21.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.290323    
7   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  0   False   22.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   1.000000    
8   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  0   False   23.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   1.000000    
9   542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  27  False   24.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.129032    
10  542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  29  False   25.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.064516    
11  542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  10  False   26.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.677419    
12  542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  31  False   27.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.000000    
13  542 4   ROOM    True    False   []  28  False   28.09.2023  31  20363   None    None    False   False   de_AT   0.096774
```